# Linux Overwrite Java Resource file

Tags: java, linux, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I want to overwrite a quartz-jobs.xml file I have in a WAR deployed in JBOSS under a Linux x86 machine.

I have tried several things but I have not been able to obtain the correct path to do it properly:

Error writing: ***/content/ThisIsMyWar.war/WEB-INF/classes/quartz-jobs.xml*** (No such file or directory)

Currently, the code is as this (but I have tried some more things without success):

```
String urlPath = null;
            String filePath = null;
            final URL url = classLoader.getResource("quartz-jobs.xml");
            if (url != null) {
                urlPath = URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "UTF-8");
            }
            if (urlPath != null) {
                filePath = urlPath;
            } else {
                filePath = new File("quartz-jobs.xml").getAbsolutePath();
            }

            final File file = new File(filePath);
            LOG.warn(String.format("File %s absolute: %s", url.getPath(), file.getAbsolutePath()));
            LOG.warn(String.format("File canonical: %s", file.getCanonicalPath()));

            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.write(newQuartzJobsXml);
```

Is it possible to overwrite the XML resource in Linux ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why its not working is because you are modifying resource read from classLoader.
This wont modify war's resource entry.

You can update war by using standard java command "jar uf" (
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html )

Steps for this can be:

1. Keep the modified "quartz-jobs.xml" in same directory where target-war is.
2. Create an executor (quartz_updader.sh) and add commands for going to right directory and updating jar:

   ***cd  #director-where-war-and-updated-xml-reside***

   ***jar uf  #target-war quartz-jobs.xml***
3. Give right permissions to (quartz_updader.sh) for execution.
4. Execute the .sh from java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command )
   where command=sudo ./quartz_updader.sh

Above was on assumption "quartz-jobs.xml" is directly under war instead of some relative location.
If it is in relative location, modify above approach to:

- create #relative-location# hierarchy next to #target-war and keep new
  "quartz-jobs.xml" under it.
- Modify the .sh file jar update command: jar
  uf #target-war   #relative-loc/quartz-jobs.xml

Comment: In Windows I could perfectly update this file just by detailing "quartz-jobs.xml" as the file path. However, in Linux it is not possible to work the same. Maybe it would be better to reschedule the jobs instead of updating this file :S. Thanks for your quick answer.